# android: shape corners do not work when setting individual corners

Tags: android

I need to have a background which has rounded bottom left/right coners(but not top left/right ones), below is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="1dp">
        <solid android:color="#FFbdbebd"/>
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="12dip"
            android:bottomRightRadius="12dip"
            android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
            android:topRightRadius="0dip"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

But the result is a plain rectangle without any corner rounded, if I only use:

```
android:radius="12dip"
```

then all corners are rounded, I searched and found a bug related to this:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9161

but the bug states:

> Left/right is switched, because android:bottomRightRadius="2dp" turned out to specify left-bottom rounded corner.

which may not be relavent to my issue, I also tried to use:

```
android:radius="12dip"
```

followed by

```
android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
android:topRightRadius="0dip"
```

without success.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found there may be a bug that if you set individual corners, and if any of them is 0, all of them become 0, so in the end I set two of them to 1dip and other two to whatever I need, as none of them is 0, so the bug does not affect it and the result looks good.

Comment: Not a bug. It is as described in the dev guide.

Answer (score 8):

It seems to be a known issue. Every corner must be >1 or else no corners will be rounded. According to the Android documentation it can be done but it's kind of hacky:

> Note: Every corner must (initially) be provided a corner radius greater than 1, or else no     corners are rounded. If you want specific corners to not be rounded, a work-around is to use  android:radius to set a default corner radius greater than 1, but then override each and every corner with the values you really want, providing zero ("0dp") where you don't want >rounded corners.

See here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#corners-element

Answer (score 7):

Change this:

```
 <corners 
        android:bottomRightRadius="12dp" 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp" 
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

to this:

```
 <corners 
        android:radius="1dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="12dp" 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp" 
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

and it should be working as expected.

Comment: android:radius="1dp" will make all the corner radius to 1dp.

Comment: Or could simply be..        <corners android:radius="12dp" android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions didn't work for me, but I found a solution online that did work: (https://medium.com/@iamsadesh/android-ui-creating-a-layout-rounded-only-in-the-top-d60514ccab77)

This is for rounding just the top corners:

```
val image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)
val curveRadius = 20F

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

    image.outlineProvider = object : ViewOutlineProvider() {

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        override fun getOutline(view: View?, outline: Outline?) {
            outline?.setRoundRect(0, 0, view!!.width, (view.height+curveRadius).toInt(), curveRadius)
        }
    }

    image.clipToOutline = true

}
```

Answer (score -12):

try this its work for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <corners 
            android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" 
            android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="30dp" 
            android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: If I set four corners to be rounded, it also work for me, but the question is I only want bottom two corners rounded which did not work.