# Create a drawable with rounded top corners and a border on bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

This is what I came up with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/grey" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp" />
            <corners 
                android:radius="0dp"/> 
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <corners 
                android:radius="1dp" 
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" 
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp" 
                android:topRightRadius="5dp"/> 
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This is working however the bottom radius is showing up whatever values I place on it.

Actually in only takes the `topLeftRadius` to make it looks like this

```
    <corners  
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp" 
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, can u add more information about the requirement or a screenshot for how it should look like?

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem, try it. it worked for me fine. I just add **android:top="10dp"** to second item. So, it causes to round just top corners.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/dialog_title_bar_blue"/>

            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/dialog_title_bar_blue"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**
there is a bug as mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9161)

**Solution:**
the bug has been solved in api12.

so give it a try by providing appropriate resources.create two xml files with same name and put one of them into `drawable` folder and another into `drawable-v12` folder.

**->** In **`drawable`** folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/grey" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp" />
        <corners 
            android:radius="0dp"/> 
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners 
            android:radius="1dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" 
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp" 
            android:topRightRadius="5dp"/> 
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

**->** In **`drawable-v12`** folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/grey" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp" />
        <corners 
            android:radius="0dp"/> 
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners 
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" 
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp" 
            android:topRightRadius="5dp"/> 
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

I hope it will be helpful !

Comment: done that , I added it because it seems to be the solution as I lurked here on SO. removing that will not do anything. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105521/android-shape-corners-do-not-work-when-setting-individual-corners

Comment: thanks for the help , however I am just targeting v17 to v18. doesn't seem to work when removing ``android:radius="1dp"``

Comment: testing on real device or emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is your solution "Cheers :) "

first add this layout as background.
Then in the below add a view as aline.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color -->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topRightRadius="3dp" />

</shape>
```

And the view

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

Comment: this one i have done in my project. Its working fine.
Does your requirement is like that u cant add a line in below
Refresh the page i have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

        <solid android:color="#800000" />

        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="3dp">
    <shape>
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

        <solid android:color="#800000" />
    </shape>
</item>
```